# Allocate space for char

Tags: c++

String construct got space for the data by doing

```
new char[strlen(cp)+1];
```

Since there are only `strlen(cp)`characters in the string, what is the extra byte for?

Comment: Probably the null terminator.

Comment: Please use `std::string` instead of raw C-style char arrays.

Comment: Why is this getting so many votes??? This is a first page of any C tutorial/

Comment: @aleguna:  I upvoted because it is a well-asked question.  Clear, to-the-point, and not ambigious.  People vote for different reasons.

Comment: questions dont have to be obscure or complex - just well asked and relevant to the asker

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For the [special `'\0'`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) char which indicates end of string.

(Remember, *C-style strings* are *null-terminated* arrays).

Additional helpful notes:

- `strlen` *does not* count the `'\0'` (That's why you need this extra *byte*).
- `strcpy` *does* copy the `'\0'`.
- `char str[7] = "String";` - Adds `'\0'` by itself.
- `char str[] = {'S','t','r','i','n','g'}` - *Does not* add `'\0'`.
- `char str[7] = {'S','t','r','i','n','g'}` - Will add `'\0'`.

Comment: Ohhhh!  Now I get why one of my programs didn't work.  I was using NULL to mark positions in the string for my own use, since it never prints any output, as opposed to most other characters, which usually print a box thing.

Comment: thats why u should use std::string; you are allowed to have null characters in a std::string (C++ keeps track of length some other way)

Comment: @AJMansfield: `NULL` is (a macro that expands to) a null *pointer* constant. Don't use it to refer to the null character; that's `'\0'`.

Comment: `char str[7] = {'S','t','r','i','n','g'}` will add `\0'`, but only coincidentally. An incomplete initializer causes the remainder of the object to be set to zero.

Comment: @KeithThompson And that character's _name_, according to various specification for character encodings with that character, is `NULL`.  Take a look [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm).

Comment: @AJMansfield: Nevertheless, `NULL` is a predefined macro in C, and using that name to refer to a character value is confusing and potentially incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In C based Strings there is always a special character at the end of string `'\0'` which also needs an extra byte.  This is why we need an extra character and we need array of `strlen(str)+1` to store the string.